# Is the Limit of the derivative of a $C^1$ function always the equal to the one-sided derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f\colon [0,\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\eps)\to\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\R$ and $f\in C^1\bigl((0,\eps)\bigr)$ and the one-sided derivative
$$f'_+(0) = \lim_{h\to +0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
should exist. Is it always true that it holds
$$ \lim_{s\to+0} f'(s) = f'_+(0) \, ?$$

Comment: Do you know that $\nabla_v f(x) = \nabla f(x) \cdot v$?

Comment: Maybe the title is misleadingly addressing to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples where such limit doesn't exist:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(\frac 1 h) & x>0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
We have
$$
f'_+(0)=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{h^2\sin(\frac 1 h)}h=0
$$
and
$$
f'(x)=2 x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
so $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Can we assume that $f'$ is bounded on $(0,\eps)$? I think we cannot, because $f\in C^1\bigl((0,\eps)\bigr)$ does not imply that $f'(s)$ remains bounded for $s\to 0$.

Comment: @Wauzl you are right, there are examples where $f'$ is not bounded even if $f'(0)$ exists, I edited

Comment: Seems to me that your example shoots down your second statement too.  You are claiming rather more than an application of the dominated convergence theorem--you are also interchanging the limits $\lim_h$ and $\lim_n$.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson you are right, my proof was incorrect but why do you think that the counterexample implies that boundedness of $f'$ is not enough to have the desired convergence?

Comment: The example that you have given provides a *bounded* derivative.  So any discussion about whether boundedness would help is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$We additionally assume that $f\in C^2\bigl((0,\eps)\bigr)$ and that 
$f''$ is bounded on $(0,\eps)$.

### Proof

The equation we want to show is essentially
$$\begin{align*}
   \lim_{h\to+0} \lim_{s\to+0} \frac{f(s+h) - f(s)}{h} = \lim_{s\to+0} \lim_{h\to+0} \frac{f(s+h) - f(s)}{h}.
\end{align*}$$

We know limits can be interchanged, when both limits exist and one of the
inner limits converges uniformly.

Define for $s>0$ the functions
$$\begin{align*}
   g_h(s) &= \frac{f(s+h) - f(s)}{h} \\
   g(s) &= f'(s) = \lim_{i\to\infty} g_i(s).
\end{align*}$$

Since $f\in C^2\bigl((0,\eps)\bigr)$ we can Taylor's theorem with Lagrange
remainder and get
get
$$
f(s+h) = f(s) + h f'(s) + \frac{h^2}2 f''(\xi_{s,h})
$$
for some $\xi_{s,h}\in(s,s+h)$.

Now consider
$$\begin{align*}
   \sup_{s\in (0,\eps)} |g_h(s) - g(s)| &= \sup_{s\in (0,\eps)} \left|\frac{h}2 f''(\xi_{s,h})\right| \\
     &= h\underbrace{\sup_{s\in (0,\eps)} \left|\frac{1}2 f''(\xi_{s,h})\right|}_{< const.} \overset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0.
\end{align*}$$

This means that $g_i(s)\to g(s)$ uniformly.
Thus, the limits may be interchanged.

---

Comments on if this is actually correct and how the premisses may be weakened are very welcome. (As well as additional answers.)

Comment: A natural weaker assumption than yours would be that "$f'$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\epsilon)$ for some positive $\epsilon$."  A necessary and sufficient condition is simply that "$\lim_{t\to0+}f'(t)$ exists and $f$ is differentiable on $[0,\epsilon]$" since continuity of the derivative is not needed.